# Strings comparison in android java

Tags: java, android, string

```
if(EditText1.getText().toString().equals("National"))
{
..  
.. 
}
```

This is actually comparing the word "National" isn't it?

My need is,it should compare the words but rest of the word "National".

Comment: _My need is,it should compare the words rest of the word "National"._ meaning? Do `if(!(EditText1.getText().toString().equals("National")))` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: The question makes absolutely no sense. Some sample values for `EditText1.getText().toString()` and the corresponding result of the comparison would help clarify the matter.

Comment: For this you have to iterate the string for every words and make comparison for it.. Or just replace the "National" word with "" in String then compare the string..

Comment: I don't get it either. My best guess is that you want to match strings that end with "National", such as "Example National" or "Blablabla National"?

Comment: yes this will compare to see if the word is "National". my understanding of your question is to see if EditTextBox1 contains the word "National" which you would need to use:   EditTextBox1.getText().toString().indexOf("National")>0

Comment: No more down vote pls.. give him time to modify question..

Comment: @andro prabu - Restructure the Question, So other user can understand it. Else you get more down votes or closed the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use not (`!`):

```
if(!EditText1.getText().toString().equals("National")){...}
```

Comment: You got my point.and its working.thanks Quoi

Comment: @KazekageGaara - sorry, I did not see your comment